# тип данных Symbol в JS

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал изучать JS. не могу понять для чего, зачем, почему и как использовать тип данных Symbol. Буду благодарен за ответ на понятном для чайника языке)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/symbol

Answer (score 0):

Symbol — это уникальный и неизменяемый тип данных, который может быть использован как ключ для свойств объектов.

В объекте ключем может выступать только строка или число. Может возникнуть такая ситуация, что имена ключей будут пересекаться, и перезаписывать значения друг друга, что является не хорошо. Но при использовании Symbol - ключи всегда будут разные. Каждый Symbol, даже с одинаковым именем, будет уникальным свойством.